# how to mkvEXTRACT.exe specific tracks via batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, extract, mkv

So here is the deal... I'm trying to extract specific tracks from mkv container via batch script using mkvextract.exe and the only way I can think about is to extract part of tracks via batch and rest of them manualy (this costs me a lot of time). Is there actualy a better, smarter, faster way to achieve this? All I would need to extract are:

all subtitle tracks with original names in folder "subs"
all attachments with original names in folder "atchmnts" **(Update: I managed this one)**
and chapters track with original name in XML format in folder "xml" **(Update: done thx to xDeathwing. tho, its not original filename as originaly requested, in this case its ok, coz there's always 1 xml file per mkv)**

I am with this so far:

```
@echo off
mkvextract.exe attachments "video.mkv" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
mkvextract.exe chapters "video.mkv" --redirect-output chapters.xml
mkvextract.exe --ui-language en tracks "video.mkv" 0:"%CD%\%~sub.ass" (Update: this one 
actually working, but I can extract only one track instead of all of them and also its not 
keeping original filename as given by mkvextract - "video_track4_eng.ass" - and also 
I assume this will work only if track ID/language was defined during muxing process)

md "atchmnts"
md "subs"
md "xml"

move "*.ttf" "atchmnts\"
move "*.otf" "atchmnts\"
move "*.png" "atchmnts\"

move "*.srt" "subs\"
move "*.ass" "subs\"
move "*.sub" "subs\"

move "*.xml" "xml\"

pause
exit
```

I am aware of https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvextract.html, but cant realy find what I looking for and fix my script.

Comment: If this is possible, it's probably mentioned in mkvextract's documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting all of the above to one single folder, and than looping thru the dir command to move all the files to the respected folders is an option

here I coded a small batch file for .xml .sub and .ext
you are free to edit the script 
also if requested I can add delete whats left option 
This batch file can also be made into a more generalised one which takes variables

```
@Echo off
if NOT exist xml md xml
if NOT exist subs md subs
if NOT exist atchmnts md atchmnts

set i=1&set j=1&set k=1
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F %%a IN ('dir /b') do (
if /I %%~xa==.xml set "xml[!i!]=%%~a"&&set /a i+=1
if /I %%~xa==.sub set "sub[!j!]=%%~a"&&set /a j+=1
if /I %%~xa==.ext set "ext[!k!]=%%~a"&&set /a k+=1
)

set /a i-=1&set /a j-=1& set /a k-=1

if %i% GTR 0 echo xml
for /L %%i in (1,1,%i%) do echo %%i- "!xml[%%i]!"&&move %~dp0\!xml[%%i]! %~dp0\xml

if %j% GTR 0 echo sub
for /L %%i in (1,1,%j%) do echo %%i- "!sub[%%i]!"&&move %~dp0\!sub[%%i]! %~dp0\sub

if %k% GTR 0 echo ext
for /L %%i in (1,1,%k%) do echo %%i- "!ext[%%i]!"&&move %~dp0\!ext[%%i]! %~dp0\ext

pause
```

Comment: not really sure how this differs from my way or even how this answers my question tho.

Comment: Welli if we don't know what parameters does mkvextract gets.. than thats at most what we can do here

Comment: I updated my post up there with better explanatory of my current state

Comment: How about 
mkvextract.exe chapters "video.mkv" --redirect-output chapters.xml


and as it seems like its getting random names you can try to do --cuesheet for every track.. and get the track names, change track names with them ?

Comment: yeah, that `--redirect-output chapters.xml` worked like a charm. thx. but not sure how exactly use that `--cuesheet`. always returns me `Error: '--cuesheet' is only allowed when extracting tracks.` any example of that, pls?

Comment: mkvextract tracks source-filename --cuesheet dest-filename1
and --cuesheet should provide some info about the track data
-c character-set variable is also responsible for the char set 
also --parse-fully might work if your file doesn't have meta tags for subtitles after the 1st track but beware, that option might take some time